# C#: how to get free time slots from google calendar

Tags: c#, google-api

I am using Google API to retrieve all entries within my Calender. 
code attached below

```
        EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
        request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
        request.ShowDeleted = false;
        request.SingleEvents = true;
        request.MaxResults = 10;
        request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;
```

I want to retrieve free time slot from Calender, is there a way to work this out ?

Answer (score 0):

As there is no API call present to get you free time for a day, instead what I did is I extracted all the invites for a day based on I  did the computation of free time